# How to recreate mauritian rupee symbol in ionic app or html page?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, currency

I thought of using strike through in Rs symbol

<strike>Rs</strike>
But it is not perfectly replicating the symbol as it has the strike through it a little higher.
So what is the best option here if I want to use the symbol in my ionic app and similarly in html page as well?

I have spent a lot of time searching for html entity for it but it is not available I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try the misc symbols in `HTML` with the `<s>`, `<del>` or `<strike>`, tag whichever works for you.

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>&#8377;</p>
<strike>&#8377;</strike><br>
<s>&#8377;</s><br>
<del>&#8377;</del><br>

<p>&#8360;</p>
<strike>&#8360;</strike><br>
<s>&#8360;</s><br>
<del>&#8360;</del>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As seen on running the code snippet none of them has the - in the upper part of rs Please reffer to the rs symbol [here](http://www.xe.com/currency/mur-mauritian-rupee)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a simple way as Gowtham Shiva suggested but Here is an example css I used to make it:

```css
.currency {
  overflow:hidden;
  position : relative;
}
.currency span:after {
  background-color: #000000;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left:1px; 
}
```

```html
<p class="currency"><span>Rs</span></p>
```

[Here is the code pen of the code](https://codepen.io/Ishan_Mahajan_bst/pen/pwLbdj)